# Constraint Layout ImageView position different in device and android studio

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-xml

This is the code of an xml layout which I am using as an recycler view item layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:background="@color/app_background">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/statusImage"
            statusIcon="@{asteroid.potentiallyHazardous}"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_status_normal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/approachDate"
            android:text="@{asteroid.closeApproachDate}"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/text_grey"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/codeName"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/codeName"
            tools:text="2022-02-08"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/codeName"
            android:text="@{asteroid.codename}"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/default_text_color"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="68347 (2001 KB67)"
            />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</layout>
```

The problem is that, in android studio the image view is shown at the right side of the layout but when it's rendered on a device it's not the same. Any reason why this is happening?

Screenshot from android studio:

[image: This is the screenshot from android studio]

Screenshot from device:
[image: Screenshot from device]

Comment: What is the parent of your layout? Could it be that the parent is defined as _wrap_content_ or with a specified width?

Comment: No. I checked parent it was match parent.

Comment: I found the issue, This was because of how I inflated the recyclerview item in the adapter file. This is how I fixed it:

`val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
val view: AsteroidListItemBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.asteroid_list_item, parent, false)
return AsteroidViewHolder(view)`